# Simplifying expressions involving Sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, summation

I am trying to use *Mathematica* to simplify a symbolic expression involving `Sum`. The expression is defined as follows:

```
y = (x - x0)^α Sum[a[n] (x - x0)^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

I am trying to use `FullySimplify` on the derivative of the expression with respect to `x` via

```
FullSimplify[D[y, x]]
```

This yields
$$(x-\text{x0})^{\alpha -1} \left(\alpha  \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a(n)
   (x-\text{x0})^n+(x-\text{x0}) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n a(n)
   (x-\text{x0})^{n-1}\right)$$
However, the expression above can be easily simplified further to 
$$(x-\text{x0})^{\alpha -1} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } ( a(n) (x-\text{x0})^n(\alpha+n) ) $$

Is there a way to "make" *Mathematica* recognise this simplification? I presume the problem has something to do with the fact that I use the unknown function `a[n]` in the expression, but I am not sure what can I do about it to get similar functionality.

I am new to *Mathematica* and would like to apologise if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Why don't you take the x dependence sitting outside into the sum   y = Sum[(x - x0)^\[Alpha] *a[n] (x - x0)^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In our case a simple and direct approach would be defining a list of rules. Here is an example:

[image]

```
rules =
  { c_ Sum[n a[n] c_^(n-1), {n, 0, Infinity}] :> Sum[n c^n a[n], {n, 0, Infinity}],
    α_ Sum[a[n] c_^n, {n, 0, Infinity}] + Sum[n a[n] c_^n, {n, 0, Infinity}] :>
    Sum[(α + n) a[n] c^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]};
```

Let's define an appropriate function for `TransformationFunctions` applying rules to an expression:

```
 tf[expr_] := expr /. rules
```

and now `FullSimplify` with `tf` does the expected transformation:

```
FullSimplify[ D[y, x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]//TraditionalForm
```

[image]

alternatively one can do this:

```
FullSimplify[ D[y, x]] //. rules
```

**Note:** Applying `rules` in `TransformationFunctions` it was quite sufficient  to play with `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) while in the latter case we had to use `rules` repeatedly i.e. with `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`)  .

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is application of series of rules to the expression, just to "teach" Mathematica of how to transform the expression. I will break the chain of transformations into steps to make it better visible.
These are your functions:

```
 expr1 = (x - x0)^α  Sum[a[n] (x - x0)^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
expr2 = D[expr1, x]
```

and here are the results:

[image]

Let us do the first transformation:

```
expr3 = expr2 /. u_*\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]v_\) -> \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\((u* v)\)\)
```

this is the result:

[image]

The second transformation:

```
 expr4 = expr3 /. (x - x0)^m_ \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(s_*\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((x - x0)\), \(q_\)]\)\) -> \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(s*\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((x - x0)\), \(q + m\)]\)\)
```

yielding

[image]

and the last one:

```
 expr5 = expr4 /. \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(u1_*
      v_\)\) + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(u2_*
      v_\)\) -> \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 
      0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\((u1 + u2)\)*v\)\)
```

gives the result:

[image]

Comment: The first and second pictures (yielded results), they look the same.