# Simplifying terms in a Sum expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, summation

I have a sum in the form of pure function

```
s = Sum[f[k], {k, 0, # - 1}] &
```

of perhaps complicated terms `f[k]`. The terms `f[k]` are fractions whose denominators and numerators are products of terms of form `Pochhammer[a, k]`, where `a` is an arbitrary (in the most cases rational) number. I know, how to simplify `f[k]`:

```
FullSimplify[f[k], Assumptions -> {k ∈ Integers, k >= 1}]
```

does the work (and I obtain `1/(k + 1)`). A call

```
FullSimplify[s[n], Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers, n >= 1}]
```

returns only

$\quad \quad \sum_{k = 0}^{n -1} f(x)$

where `f[k]` remains in the complicated form. So the question is

> How do I simplify the terms of `f[k]` when they are *hidden* in a sum?

In the specific case of the given example, the goal is to obtain a sum with terms `1/(k + 1)`, or, even better, `HarmonicNumber[n]`.

Among the other things, I've taken a look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31135/simplifying-expressions-involving-sum), but the problem is that I do not know the exact form of my terms; also, I would like to have an approach that works for sums of sums (of ... ) of any described terms.

**Edit:**
On of the `f`'s is

$\texttt{f} = \frac{\texttt{Product[Pochhammer[aa,#],{aa,{3,1}}] Product[Pochhammer[cc+1,#],{cc,{}}]}}{\texttt{Product[Pochhammer[bb,#],{bb,{4}}] Product[Pochhammer[cc,#],{cc,{}}]}}\text{&}$

Comment: Hard to say without explicit code, but have you tried `s = Sum[FullSimplify[f[k], 
    Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Integers, k >= 1}], {k, 0, # - 1}] &` and then calling `s[n]`? `Sum` will symbolically evaluate it's summand when the index bounds are either symbolic (which is the case here) or the number of terms exceeds $10^6$, and so it should first evaluate `FullSimplify[f[k], 
    Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Integers, k >= 1}]` and then `Sum` the result, which should yield a `HarmonicNumber` expression. This reverses the order of summation and simplification. Is this what you need.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't include my code, because it is far from being self-explanatory and quite long, so I pointed out only the essential facts in this question. Thank you.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Although I suppose that might seem trivially easy to someone with your experience I think it is not so obvious to newer users.  I would rather that you posted that in an answer than have this question closed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: True; I probably would post an answer if explicit code for `f[k]` was provided, but at the moment I'm having trouble thinking of an example `f[k]` to illustrate the property.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I have added an example of `f[k]`.